# remove dataframe from another without removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe df1 of size [21,4], and a dataframe df2 of size [10200,4].
I wish to remove the values of df1 from df2 so that its size is [10179,4]

I have seen many posts using the drop duplicates function, however i do not want to drop any duplicates in the df2 dataframe, i only want to remove the df1 values. 
i have tried

```
result=df1[~df1[['decel','accel','corner','vert']].apply(lambda x: np.in1d(x,df2).all(),axis=1)]\.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but with no success!
many thanks for all your help

UPDATE:
Using the code:

```
Xfinal = pd.merge(X, dropthese, on=['decel','accel','corner','vert'], how='outer', indicator=True).query("_merge != 'both'").drop('_merge', axis=1)
```

allows me to remove df1 from df2, however reorders df2, grouping similar values. Is there a way to keep the order the same? thanks

Comment: If solution not working, can you add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Could you sort on the index of `df2` after you've removed the `df1` values to maintain the order?  Or create some kind of key indicating the order you want to preserve before doing the merge?